# Puppeteer on Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't work

Tags: command-line, 16.04, server, maas, javascript

Is it possible to run [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) on Ubuntu Server 16.04? I get this error.

```
(node:23213) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/root/bin/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/root/bin/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:750:14)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/root/bin/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:739:50)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:333:22)
    at Interface.close (readline.js:414:8)
    at Socket.onend (readline.js:192:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:333:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1201:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(node:23213) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23213) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How do I troubleshoot this failure and get the app to run?

Comment: `apt install puppeteer` (and all required files for my app). Used npm to run it with node.js. I made a .js script which uses puppeteer, and I want to run it using `node myapp.js` but it fails at ''puppeteer.launch()''. I tried some guides from the internet about this but didn't worked for me, and I really need it. I might change my ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 if no one can help me, but I don't know if that will make the situation any better.

Comment: Follow directions from here and it will work for you. [Official Troubleshooting Docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I had to update my Linux (sudo-apt get update) then get the libraries. It won't work if you don't update it.

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

After that, I had to add `'--no-sandbox',` on launch code (from myapp.js).

Answer (score 1):

With the most recent version of chromium here is what worked for me. Notice the recently added dependency.

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnotify-dev
sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1
sudo apt-get install libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb
#recently added dependency
sudo apt-get install libgbm-dev
```

If you are using Docker you can add the following to the Docker file. I tested with Docker as well and this works.

```
RUN apt-get update && \ apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnotify-dev \ libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 \ libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb \ libgbm-dev
```

When making the call to puppeteer added the argument `'--no-sandbox'`.  This is the same as what Lmao suggests. I was not able to get it to work without this option.

For reference I am using Ubuntu 20 but this should work with any distro.